# Ansible: Replacing with_items by loop

Tags: ansible

##### Scenario:

Changing logrotation to daily in all logrotate-config files.

- /etc/logrotate.d/*
- /etc/logrotate.conf

##### Tasks:

1. Getting list of files in /etc/logrotate.d

```
- find:
    paths: /etc/logrotate.d/
  register: logrotate_d
```

2. Changing log rotation in config files

```
- replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: '^(\s*)(daily|weekly|monthly|yearly)$'
    replace: "\\1daily"
  with_items: 
    - { path: "/etc/logrotate.conf" }
    - "{{ logrotate_d.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

##### Question:

How can I replace **with_items** by **loop** without running in to the following error:

```
'list object' has no attribute 'path'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences between the behaviour of `with_items` and `loop` as documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html). Quoting the relevant bit below:

> ... `with_items` performed implicit single-level flattening ...

So when you supply 2 lists to `with_items` they are flattened to 1 list and each item's path attribute is available. Whereas with `loop`, the second list `logrotate_d.files` remains a separate list, and that's why `item.path` attribute cannot be accessed.

For your use `with_items` seems more suitable. However if you do want to use it with `loop` you can write it as:

```yaml
- replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: '^(\s*)(daily|weekly|monthly|yearly)$'
    replace: "\\1daily"
  loop: "{{ [ { 'path': '/etc/logrotate.conf' } ] + logrotate_d.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```